# Android Studio builds a debug apk but doesn't deploy/run on device

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm struggling with coming to terms with Andoid Studio after years working with Eclipse. I've imported an existing Eclipse simple project into AStudio 1.1.0 and altough it builds an APK

> Directory of
> C:\dev\projects\AndroidStudio\DiddyOsmdroid\TinyOsmdroid\build\out
> puts\apk
>
> 25/02/2015  17:02           176,517 TinyOsmdroid-debug-unaligned.apk
>
> 25/02/2015  17:02           176,518 TinyOsmdroid-debug.apk

It doesn't deploy to a tablet connected via USB. (It did the first time I tried it, but not now) I've edited the run configurations to try both 'USB' and 'choose'. I try to deploy and run by double clicking assembleDebug as suggested in the docs. The device is visible in the Android window, in that Log lines are shown.

My gradle file looks like:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 7
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "osmdemo.demo"
        minSdkVersion 3
        targetSdkVersion 3
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("c:/users/me/some.keystore")
            storePassword "xxxxxxxxxxx"
            keyAlias "some_alias"
            keyPassword "yyyyyy"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/osmdroid-android-4.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/slf4j-android-1.5.8.jar')
}
```

I'd be grateful to get any suggestions.

Comment: From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-studio.html), it says "Once set up and your device is connected via USB, install your application on the device by selecting Run > Run (or Run > Debug) from the Android Studio menu bar."

Comment: You never mention whether or not you actually hit "Run" or not. You could just be generating an APK for all we know.

Answer (score 0):

Gradle wont excute the app on the emulator/device. It will only build and install. You have to run an adb command to run the app. This is essentially what the Run button on Android Studio does for you.

Comment: This is not true. `gradle installDebug` will install the app.

Comment: You are correct @yole. I meant to say Gradle wont 'run' the the app. I have updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: The run button doesn't install on the device and therefore can't run the apk. It causes assembleDebug to execute.

Comment: Did you find any solution to these, coz i also got same error as you are,
When i am running project on Studio which was my Eclipse project.
It shows me these error:
**I/O Error: E:\MyProject\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk (The system cannot find the file specified)**
I didn't generate apk in that folder yet so why it showing that kind of error? Is anyone know that kind of error please help me, i am working on it from yesterday. :(